# PXImport not working properly in some screens

Tags: c#, acumatica, acumatica-kb

I tried inserting the upload button on the screens below but failed to achieved the desired result. I have enabled the **Allow Upload** mode in Customization Project Editor and inserted the **PXImport** on the views as well.

1. Release Production Orders - the [dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnxSU.png) shows wrong properties

   ```
    [PXFilterable]
    [PXImport(typeof(AMProdItem))]
    public PXProcessing<AMProdItem,
        Where<AMProdItem.statusID, Equal<ProductionOrderStatus.planned>,
            And<AMProdItem.hold, Equal<False>,
            And<Where<AMProdItem.function, Equal<OrderTypeFunction.regular>,
                Or<AMProdItem.function, Equal<OrderTypeFunction.disassemble>>>>>>> PlannedOrds;
   ```
2. Sales Prices - causes the [grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ad1xJ.jpg) to not preload the list and successful import doesn't show here at all

   ```
        [PXFilterable]
        [PXImport(typeof(ARSalesPrice))]
        public PXSelectJoin<ARSalesPrice,
        LeftJoin<InventoryItem, On<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<ARSalesPrice.inventoryID>>,
        LeftJoin<INItemClass, On<INItemClass.itemClassID, Equal<ARSalesPrice.itemClassID>>,
        LeftJoin<CR.BAccount, On<CR.BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<ARSalesPrice.customerID>>,
        LeftJoin<INSite, On<ARSalesPrice.siteID, Equal<INSite.siteID>>>>>>,
        Where2<Where<CR.BAccount.bAccountID, IsNull, Or<Match<CR.BAccount, Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>>,
        And2<Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, IsNull, Or<Match<InventoryItem, Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>>,
        And2<Where<INItemClass.itemClassID, IsNull, Or<Match<INItemClass, Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>>,
        And2<Where<ARSalesPrice.siteID, IsNull, Or<Match<INSite, Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>>,
        And<ARSalesPrice.itemStatus, NotIn3<INItemStatus.inactive, InventoryItemStatus.unknown, INItemStatus.toDelete>,
        And2<Where<ARSalesPrice.isFairValue, NotEqual<True>, Or<FeatureInstalled<FeaturesSet.aSC606>>>,
        And2<Where<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.priceType>, Equal<PriceTypes.allPrices>, Or<ARSalesPrice.priceType, Equal<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.priceType>>>>,
        And2<Where<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.taxCalcMode>, Equal<PriceTaxCalculationMode.allModes>,
            Or<ARSalesPrice.taxCalcMode, Equal<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.taxCalcMode>>>>,
        And2<Where<ARSalesPrice.customerID, Equal<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.priceCode>>, Or<ARSalesPrice.custPriceClassID, Equal<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.priceCode>>, Or<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.priceCode>, IsNull>>>,
        And2<Where<ARSalesPrice.inventoryID, Equal<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.inventoryID>>, Or<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.inventoryID>, IsNull>>,
        And2<Where<ARSalesPrice.siteID, Equal<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.siteID>>, Or<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.siteID>, IsNull>>,
        And2<Where2<Where2<Where<ARSalesPrice.effectiveDate, LessEqual<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.effectiveAsOfDate>>, Or<ARSalesPrice.effectiveDate, IsNull>>,
        And<Where<ARSalesPrice.expirationDate, GreaterEqual<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.effectiveAsOfDate>>, Or<ARSalesPrice.expirationDate, IsNull>>>>,
        Or<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.effectiveAsOfDate>, IsNull>>,
        And<Where2<Where<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.itemClassCD>, IsNull,
                Or<INItemClass.itemClassCD, Like<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.itemClassCDWildcard>>>>,
            And2<Where<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.inventoryPriceClassID>, IsNull,
                Or<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.inventoryPriceClassID>, Equal<ARSalesPrice.priceClassID>>>,
            And2<Where<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.ownerID>, IsNull,
                Or<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.ownerID>, Equal<ARSalesPrice.priceManagerID>>>,
            And2<Where<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.myWorkGroup>, Equal<False>,
                     Or<ARSalesPrice.priceWorkgroupID, IsWorkgroupOfContact<CurrentValue<ARSalesPriceFilter.currentOwnerID>>>>,
            And<Where<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.workGroupID>, IsNull,
                Or<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.workGroupID>, Equal<ARSalesPrice.priceWorkgroupID>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>,
            OrderBy<Asc<ARSalesPrice.inventoryCD,
                    Asc<ARSalesPrice.priceType,
                    Asc<ARSalesPrice.uOM, Asc<ARSalesPrice.breakQty, Asc<ARSalesPrice.effectiveDate>>>>>>> Records;
   ```

Any idea on why PXImport doesn't work for these screens or causes the data not to show?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the DAC provided to the PXImport attribute on the view is that of the primary view of the graph.

Comment: I am pretty sure I have done it on the primary view of the graphs.

Comment: So the type provided in the PXImport attribute is that of the primary and it is still not working? Example if you were to do it on the SOOrderEntry graph the attribute would be [PXImport(SOOrder)]

Comment: Both **PXImport** have been decorated with their primary view as shown in the codes above; `[PXImport(typeof(AMProdItem))]` and `[PXImport(typeof(ARSalesPrice))]`. It is indeed working for **Sales Prices** screen, but the grid doesn't preload its list and upon successful import, it won't show any results on the grid.